# Unix merge 2 csv files with different Headers

Tags: unix

file1.csv

```
header1, header2, header3, header4, header5
a, b, c, d, e
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt trying to solve this?

Comment: yes solved it on equal and soreted columns but wasnt able on unequal number of columns

Comment: Please update your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general case: keeps track of all the headers seen

the data:

```
$ cat file1.csv
header1, header2, header3, header4, header5
a, b, c, d, e

$ cat file2.csv
header1, header3, header4, header5
j, w, c, a

$ cat file3.csv
header1, header2, header3, header5, header6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

file1 is missing header6
file2 is missing header2 and header6
file3 is missing header4

the code:

```
awk -F ", " -v OFS="," '
    FNR == 1 {
        delete this_file_headers
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            this_file_headers[i] = $i
            if (!($i in all_headers)) {
                all_headers[$i]
                all_headers_ordered[++nhead] = $i
            } 
        }
        next
    }
    {
        lineno++
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            data[lineno,this_file_headers[i]] = $i
    }
    END {
        sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<=nhead; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, all_headers_ordered[i]
            sep=FS
        }
        print ""

        for (i=1; i<=lineno; i++) {
            sep = ""
            for (j=1; j<=nhead; j++) {
                printf "%s%s", sep, data[i,all_headers_ordered[j]]
                sep=FS
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3}.csv
```

the output

```
header1, header2, header3, header4, header5, header6
a, b, c, d, e, 
j, , w, c, a, 
1, 2, 3, , 4, 5
```

Comment: header1, header2, header3, header4, header5
a,b,c,d,e

header1, header2, header4
a,b,c

header6
x

and the ouput

`header1, header2, header3, header4, header5, header6
a,b,c,d,e, , , , ,
a,b,c, , , , ,
, , , , , x
`
Not accurate and giving excess of ,

Comment: cannot reproduce this on fedora with gawk/nawk/mawk. What's your plaform and awk version?

Comment: i can reproduce it, but for a big file, some header matching is correct some other is not... do you have any clue why ?

Comment: With that problem description? No idea.

Comment: please check my edited post with a clear update about the situation. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with paste command;

```
paste -d'\n' file1.csv <(awk -F',' 'NR>1{print $1",  ,"$2","$3","$4}' file2.csv)
```

with awk;

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0}; NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next} ; FNR > 1 {print a[FNR]"\n" $1"  , "$2" "$3" "$4}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

eg;

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ awk 'NR==1{print $0}; NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next} ; FNR > 1 {print a[FNR]"\n" $1"  , "$2" "$3" "$4}' file1.csv file2.csv 
header1, header2, header3, header4, header5
a, b, c, d, e
j,  , w, c, a
```

Comment: not working :/

awk 'NR==1{print $0}; NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next} ; FNR > 1 {print a[FNR]"\n" $1"  , "$2" "$3" "$4}' file1.csv file2.csv 



`header1, header2, header3, header4, header5

a,b,c,d,e
j,w,c,a  ,`

Comment: it just works on this example, only if header 2 is skipped , if header 4 is skipped won't work

Comment: @Johnny : could you provide more example on csv files

Comment: i need a general rule, not just for a specific file like the one glenn did, yours work only on this example